Mercurial: get only a specific, nested folder from a subrepo
I'm aware that similar questions have been asked in the past, however, since the newest of them are pushing on being a decade old, I feel it's reasonable to try again with my particular problem.
I have a very specific need I'd like to accomplish with Mercurial: in the context of a larger, private repo (a video game), I ended up authoring a couple plugins for the engine being used, and would like to share those publically as separate repos, whilst still being able to share history with the files embedded in my private repo.
Because of the requirements of the engine, in order to be functional, plugins must reside in a particular location, relative to the main project config file:
game/
├── addons/
│   ├── third-party-plugin/
│   ├── my-plugin/
│   └── my-other-plugin/
└── project.cfg

The game/addons/ directory is shared amongst all installed plugins, so a single plugin must keep all its files underneath its assigned subdirectory.
On the other hand, for the publically shared repos, additional files are needed at the top level; at least a README and a licence file. Furthermore, because of the (near lack of) distribution format for plugins, each repo must also contain an addons/ directory in order to create an installable distribution:
http://somewhere.host/my-plugin-repo/
├── README.md
├── LICENSE.txt
├── docs/
├── addons/
│   └── my-plugin/
└── example-project.cfg

http://somewhere.host/my-other-plugin-repo/
├── README.md
├── LICENSE.txt
├── screenshots/
├── addons/
│   └── my-other-plugin/
└── example-project.cfg

My requirements:

Be able to edit files and commit directly under game/addons/my-plugin/, before propagating the changes to my-plugin-repo. That's important, since it is ultimately the context in which I need the plugins I end up writing, and the place I can reasonably try them out. A separate repo's checkout will be seen as a different project by the engine, and nothing outside the directory in which the project config file resides is visible to the engine
If any changes are made directly in the external my-plugin-repo/addons/my-plugin repo, I should be able to pull them into game/addons/my-plugin, so any outside contributions, etc. can be accepted easily without causing history to diverge
Only the directory my-plugin-repo/addons/my-plugin should be pulled from/pushed to by game/addons/my-plugin. Any files outside of addons/my-plugin should be ignored for the purpose of synchronisation; game/addons/ must still be shared with other plugins that have nothing to do with that particular plugin's external repo, including my other plugins with their own repos
Symlinks from another location on the file system are a no-go. I need this setup to replicate easily and stay in sync on multiple machines, including Windows
Not all the users working on the game know anything about the plugins I'm developing or have a lot of experience with version control. There should not be any special steps that don't happen automatically during a pull that are required to get and retain a fully functional copy of everything in the game's repo, including all the plugins
It shouldn't be so brittle that I will be fully and thoroughly hosed if I ever make a mistake without realising and undoing it immediately. I have previously tried a similar thing with git subrepo, and it ended up breaking so hard it was impossible to recover without fully purging the affected history and restarting from scratch. I'd like this to be at least slightly more robust.

I've tried to think up various combinations of subrepos, narrow/sparse clones, and convert to achieve that, but I couldn't come up with a viable strategy. I'm willing to accept some friction during a push from game/addons/my-plugin to my-plugin-repo, or extra steps in order to update the external revision referenced by game/addons/my-plugin, as long as subsequent pulls from game-repo by other users are transparent. If I need to run a script that does some convert magic under the hood, and/or shuttle changes through an intermediate repo sitting next to my game checkout, or set up some hooks, that is all acceptable, so long as there is not a need for more than at most one-time special setup per clone of the repo.
